# Invalid argument supplied foreach

Tags: php, foreach

We have taken over a custom built CMS for a client and having problems getting it to run on a new server. We get this error:

```
PHP Warning: in file /var/www/vhosts/ds8760.dedicated.turbodns.co.uk/eera-bioenergy.com/application/modules/cms/models/Menu.php on line 117: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The line in question is:

```
foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
```

where $menu is set just before, like so:

```
$menu  = is_null($menu) ? $this->getMenu() : $menu;
```

getMenu is:

```
    public function getMenu() {
    return $this->_menu;
```

and _menu is set at the top as so:

```
private $_menu;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

edit: this isn't the same as the "duplicate" you listed. This is a custom css and im trying to work out where it is failing.

Comment: What is the type of `$_menu`?

Comment: Hi, sorry to sound stupid but what do you mean? how can i check this?

Comment: private $_menu = array(); should do the trick. The error is there because $_menu isn't an array.